# Javascript: OnClick to Open in Native App vs Browser Window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, append, native, apple-maps

Currently, my onClick function opens Google Maps in an external window. The phone app opens correctly BUT also opens an unnecessary browser window (from window.open).

How should my onClick functions be written so, by default, the user opens the location or phone number in their respective native map and phone app, rather than the browser window?

I’m using Google Map’s shorted urls, Stackoverflow won’t let me post the https:// address in my code, so bear with me.

(https://… goo.gl/maps/4f6F9ThfsJ72).

I know I should be using standard HTML links rather than type='submit’. I also realize it’s redundant to use the "Tele" and "Phone" values, but it’s how I got it working with type='submit'.

Thanks in advance!

```
function arrayData() {
    var index;
    var text = "<ul>";
    var htmlTable = '';
    var test = [];
    test = [{
        Id: "Empire State Building",
        Location: "goo.gl/maps/xhxyYDo5H9E2",
        Street: "350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118",
        Tele: "tel:1-XXX-XXX-XXXX"
        Phone: "1-XXX-XXX-XXXX"
    }];

    for (index = 0; index < test.length; index++) {
        var streetTextBoxId = "streetTextBox" + index;
        var locationTextBoxId = "locationTextBox" + index;
        var teleTextBoxId = "teleTextBox" + index;
        var phoneTextBoxId = “phoneTextBox " + index;

        $("#test tbody").append("<tr><td>" + test[index].Id + "' />" + "</td> <td>" + "<input id='" + locationTextBoxId + "' type='submit' onClick=window.open('" + test[index].Location + "') value='" + test[index].Street + "' />" + "</td> <td>" + "<input id='" + teleTextBoxId + "' type='submit' onClick=window.open('" + test[index].Tele + "') value='" + test[index].Phone + "' />" + "</td> </tr>");
    }
}
```